# Random character from a string

Tags: code-golf, string

Your goal in this [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) is to pick a random character from a string. If a character appears X times, and there are Y characters, then the chance of that character being picked will be X/Y.

#### Input

The program takes a string as an input.

#### Output

Your program outputs a character.

#### Examples

- `xyz`: x, y, or z
- `xxX`: x, x, or X
- `}^€`: }, ^, or €
- `xxx`: x
- `0123456789`: random number, 0-9

Comment: In the future, please use the Sandbox for your challenges. If one user posts four very short answers in quick succession, that's a good sign your challenge is trivial.

Comment: Posting the same comment on every single answer is really unnecessary, especially if the answers are 1 byte long and thus must consist of a random-choice built-in.

Comment: What characters will the string contain? Is it alright if the probability is not exactly uniform?

Comment: lol 6 ansers from one user!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because:

Too Narrow

There are either too few possible ways to answer, or answers would only differ in the language used.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 1 byte

```
O
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=O&input=%22xyz%22&debug=0)

#### Explanation

From the [definition](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/rev-doc.txt) of the operator `O`:

```
op. arg.    func.
O   <col>   Random element of A.
```

Comment: The Pyth executer doesn't work on mobile. I will try it when I can use a computer; can someone else verify this works?

Comment: @Peanut It works perfectly.

Comment: @Peanut It works fine on mine mobile, what OS/Browser are/were you using? I'd like to make it more general.

Comment: @isaacg, I was using iOS 10 developer beta 1, and Safari 10.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
X
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=WA&input=&args=J3h5eic)

#### Explanation

From the [definition](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Atoms) of the operator `X`:

> Arity: 1
>
> Name: Random
>
> Function: choose a random item from z if z is a list, or from 1 to z inclusive if z is a positive integer. If z = 0, return z. Error if z is negative or a decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 3 bytes

```
lmR
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=bG1S&input=eHl6)

```
lmR
l    read line
 mR  random element
```

Answer (score 1):

## 05AB1E, 2 bytes

```
.R
```

from `Info.txt`:

```
.R      = pop a      push random_pick(a)
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=LlI&input=YWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXo&debug=on)

Answer (score 1):

## C, 30 bytes

This answer must run on a 32-bit platform and requires the GNU C library implementation.

```
f(s){return*(char*)strfry(s);}
```

The [`strfry`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/strfry.html#strfry) function shuffles the characters in a string. We first shuffle the input string, then return the first character.

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 1 byte

```
J
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=Sg&input=Inh5eiI)

#### Explanation

From the [definition](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/blob/master/docs/commands.txt) of the operator `J`:

> `4A (J): pop a: push a random integer in [0,a) (randrange(a)); pop [a] or "a": push a random element from [a] or "a" (random.choice([a]|"a"))`

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/), 5 bytes

```
?@#{]
```

### Usage

```
>> f =: ?@#{]
>> f 'xyz'
<< x
```

### Explanation

This is a [fork](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/fork), where `f` is `?@#`, `g` is `{`, and `h` is `]`.

Therefore, `(?@#{])'xyz'`, when expanded, would become `((?@#)'xyz') ({) ((])'xyz')`

The `(?@#)` is just a [composed function](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/at), so `(?@#)'xyz'` expanded would become `?(#'xyz')`.

`#'xyz'` gets the length of `'xyz'`, then `?` generates a random non-negative integer below the length.

The `{` then takes the item at the corresponding index.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.5 and Python 2.7, 26 bytes:

```
from random import*;choice
```

A function declaration. Name the function, and then call it like `print(<Function Name>(<String>))`.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 44 bytes

```java
x->x.charAt((int)(Math.random()*x.length()))
```

[Try it online!](http://goo.gl/B1inQj)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 40 bytes

```javascript
x=>x[Math.floor(x.length*Math.random())]
```

```js
f=x=>x[Math.floor(x.length*Math.random())]
alert(f(prompt()))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 11 bytes

```perl6
*.comb.pick
```

```perl6
*.comb.roll
```

#### Explanation:

- `*` starts the Whatever lambda
- `.comb` splits the string into a list of grapheme clusters
- `.roll`/`.pick` grabs a single element from the list at random
  ( so it is effectively a weighted roll )

( There isn't a difference between `.pick` and `.roll` unless you give them an argument that is something other than `1` )

#### Usage:

```perl6
say ( *.comb.pick )( 'xxX' ); # ⅔ chance of ｢x｣, ⅓ chance of ｢X｣

my &code = *.comb.pick;

say code 'xyz'; # ⅓ chance of each of ｢x｣ ｢y｣ or ｢z｣

say ('}^€:','0123456789').map: *.comb.pick;
```

Answer (score 0):

## q (4)

Will return a random item from a list:

```
rand
```